# fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Im making my first app at the moment and ive run into a problem: fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5). this message is logged by log cat when i run my app on my phone. Im using the acellerometer in my program and i have a suspicion that its the problem although i told it to log:

```
sensors = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    acell = sensors.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    if(acell==null){
        System.err.print("ERROR: Failed to get the sensor(TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)");
    }
```

the message never gets logged! The first lines of the log are:

```
10-29 09:52:38.575  14098-14098/largebulletcollider.google.com.androidgameprogramming E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-29 09:52:38.701  14098-14098/largebulletcollider.google.com.androidgameprogramming I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 7.333MB for 1077520-byte allocation
10-29 09:52:39.604  14098-14098/largebulletcollider.google.com.androidgameprogramming W/MMUMapper﹕ fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)
10-29 09:52:39.620  14098-14098/largebulletcollider.google.com.androidgameprogramming I/SurfaceView﹕ Changes: creating=true format=true size=true visible=true left=true top=true mUpdateWindowNeeded=false mReportDrawNeeded=false redrawNeeded=false forceSizeChanged=true mVisible=false mRequestedVisible=true
10-29 09:52:39.622  14098-14098/largebulletcollider.google.com.androidgameprogramming I/SurfaceView﹕ Cur surface: Surface(name=null, identity=-1)
10-29 09:52:39.638  14098-14098/largebulletcollider.google.com.androidgameprogramming I/SurfaceView﹕ New surface: Surface(name=null, identity=515), vis=true, frame=Rect(0, 0 - 320, 480)
10-29 09:52:39.638  14098-14098/largebulletcollider.google.com.androidgameprogramming I/SurfaceView﹕ visibleChanged -- surfaceCreated
10-29 09:52:39.639  14098-14098/largebulletcollider.google.com.androidgameprogramming I/SurfaceView﹕ surfaceChanged -- format=4 w=320 h=480
10-29 09:52:39.640  14098-14098/largebulletcollider.google.com.androidgameprogramming I/SurfaceView﹕ surfaceRedrawNeeded
10-29 09:52:39.640  14098-14098/largebulletcollider.google.com.androidgameprogramming I/SurfaceView﹕ finishedDrawing
10-29 09:52:39.652  14098-14098/largebulletcollider.google.com.androidgameprogramming I/SurfaceView﹕ Changes: creating=false format=false size=false visible=false left=false top=false mUpdateWindowNeeded=false mReportDrawNeeded=true redrawNeeded=false forceSizeChanged=false mVisible=true mRequestedVisible=true
10-29 09:52:39.653  14098-14098/largebulletcollider.google.com.androidgameprogramming I/SurfaceView﹕ Cur surface: Surface(name=null, identity=515)
10-29 09:52:39.657  14098-14098/largebulletcollider.google.com.androidgameprogramming I/SurfaceView﹕ New surface: Surface(name=null, identity=515), vis=true, frame=Rect(0, 0 - 320, 480)
10-29 09:52:39.657  14098-14098/largebulletcollider.google.com.androidgameprogramming I/SurfaceView﹕ surfaceRedrawNeeded
10-29 09:52:39.658  14098-14098/largebulletcollider.google.com.androidgameprogramming I/SurfaceView﹕ finishedDrawing
```

my manifest.xml is:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/red_square"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN">
            </action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: I'm guessing the emulator doesn't have this sensor? You should probably put the call in a try catch so it doesn't crash your whole application.

Comment: you see, im not running it on an emulator. im running it on my phone.

Comment: But you aren't handling exceptions at all here. Have you verified that the format you are trying to use is actually supported by your phone?